# Understanding MultiThreading and Locks Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to understand the following code: What does it mean for a Thread (say Thread1) to acquire a lock, does this mean that no other method can run until Thread1 has released its lock?

```
import threading
import time

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        # Get lock to synchronize threads
        threadLock.acquire()
        print_time(self.name, self.counter, 3)
        # Free lock to release next thread
        threadLock.release()

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
        counter -= 1

threadLock = threading.Lock()
threads = []

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Add threads to thread list
threads.append(thread1)
threads.append(thread2)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

print "Exiting Main Thread"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lock is a way to ensure that at most one thread at a time is executing a critical section. It is an object with two states, locked and unlocked. If it is unlocked, a call to its `acquire()` method locks it. If a second call to `acquire()` (usually by another thread) is made, this call blocks the calling thread until someone (usually the first thread) releases the lock with the `release()` method. Only then can the second thread continue.

In your example, the lock ensures that the thread that "gets it first" will print all lines in the `print_time()` function before the second thread prints anything. If you remove/comment the `acquire()` and `release()` calls, the difference should be obvious.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects